# How to fix error "ImportError: No module named 'selenium'" on Windows?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm, anaconda

I am using Pycharm with anaconda to work in Python. I need to use selenium webdriver. Line in code `from selenium import webdriver`  triggers error

> ImportError: No module named 'selenium'.

I tried command `conda install -c conda-forge selenium`, but error still appears.

Comment: Have you tried going to **Settings -> Project Interpreter** and seeing if selenium is listed there? Are you using that same conda Python interpreter for your project?

Comment: @MihaiChelaru, yes I checked interpreter . It uses Python 3.5 C:\Anaconda3\envs\first try\python.exe https://www.screencast.com/t/7rAvtIAdB , but I don't see selenium anywhere.

Comment: @MihaiChelaru, I added selenium package to the pycharm. It looks like that error is resolved.